# Get part of string from 1st character to next space?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a chat bot in node.js and what I need to do is monitor the messages sent in the chat. A command will begin with '!' and I need to check if there is anything sent after the command for example '!command hello there' If there is anything after '!command' it won't do anything how can i check for anything after !(string)?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `command` is `do` and `args` is `something`

```
var text = '!do something'
var rx = /^!(\w+)\s(.*)$/

var matches = text.match(rx)

if (matches) {
  var command = matches[1]
  var args = matches[2]
  // do something with the command and args here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you have made it very easy to understand. That last part was the part I was looking for too.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a loop in javascript.

```
var s = "Some String"
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == " ") {
       //Do something on space
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If string begins with `!` character, try using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/(!(?=[a-z0-9-]+))|([^\1]+)/g` to match `!` character, portion of string that is not first capture group

```js
var str = "!command hello there"    
var res = str.match(/(!(?=[a-z0-9-]+))|([^\1]+)/g);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a great place to use a regular expression. You can try creating different regex here: http://www.regexr.com/

The documentation for regular expressions in javascript can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

An example using '!(\w+)\s+(.+)' as the regular expression:

```
var str = '!command say hello';
var args = str.match(!(\w+)\s+(.+)/)

console.log(args); //["!command say hello", "command", "say hello"]
```

In the example above args[1] will have the command typed, and args[2] will have anything supplied after the command. Noe the '!' and leading space have been removed.

Comment: This would better serve as a comment.